# How do I set background image in the timeline

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am trying to set background image in the timeline of google glassware.

How do I do it?
How do I get image in view page?

I try to set image url as attachment like

```
TimelineItem timelineItem = new TimelineItem(); 
timelineItem.setText("Hello world"); 
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(contentType, attachment); 
service.timeline().insert(timelineItem, mediaContent).execute();
```

then `service.timeline().insert(timelineItem, mediaContent).execute();` gives null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [Google Mirror API Playground](https://developers.google.com/glass/playground)?

One of the templates shows a timeline card with a full-bleed background image, using this html for the card:

```
<article class="photo">
  <img src="%background-image-url%" width="100%" height="100%">
  <div class="photo-overlay"></div>
  <section>
    <p class="text-auto-size">%CardText&</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Alternatively you can also add the image you want as attachment and only provide the `text` part in the timeline item. This will use the attached image as full-bleed background image and display the `text` on top, as described here: https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#inserting_a_timeline_item_with_media

Comment: I try to set image url as attachment like `TimelineItem timelineItem = new TimelineItem();
timelineItem.setText("Hello world");
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(contentType, attachment);
service.timeline().insert(timelineItem, mediaContent).execute();` then `service.timeline().insert(timelineItem, mediaContent).execute();` gives null pointer exception.

Comment: Could you edit your original question and include the code you tried. Will be easier to read than in the comments, thanks.